# Datastage challenge

Tags: unix, datastage

I have multiple txt files, each with 1 million records (Say 10 files) and these files are saved in `LIST_OF_FILES.txt`.

I have created a sequence and parallel job to extract data from those files to load into the tables (db2).

Just imagine, I am done with first 2 files.  While loading the 3rd file (consider 10000 records are loaded into table so far), the parallel job got aborted due some environmental issue.

Now I want to load records from 10001, where the job got aborted.

*JOB DESIGN*

1. Execute command activity_1: `wc -l LIST_OF_FILES.txt.`
2. Starting loop: Start:1 , Step: 1 , To: output of Execute command activity_1.
3. Execute command activity_2: `head -output_loop_counter LIST_OF_FILES.txt | tail -1.`
4. parallel job: extract job to load records from file to table.
5. Execute command activity_3: Moving the extracted file to another folder.
6. End loop: above steps will continue till last file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an out-of-the-box capability.  You need a job design that keeps track of the number of records processed, so that you can restart from a known good point. Keep in mind, too, that any pending transactions are rolled back if a job aborts - your design probably needs to check how many rows were actually loaded into the target table.

Answer (score 0):

I would maintain the above sequence design and alter the extract job to perform a lookup against the target table on your UC/Primary key for the table, assuming that you have one.

Set failed lookup to reject, and connect your load stage to the reject link. You can dump the valid lookups into a copy stage to dead-end them and get rid of them. This slightly mimics the change capture stage, but with no sorting requirement and no warnings on values.